# What is causing these 2 errors in LogCat for eclipse(android) using ksoap2 library?

Tags: android, ksoap2

Here are 2 errors which were logged in logcat while running my app on the emulator:

```
02-09 13:44:10.470: W/dalvikvm(1334): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4033: Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;.getProperty (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

02-09 13:44:10.492: E/dalvikvm(1334): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.example.androidapp.NextPage.soap
```

What could be causing these errors and how can I solve them? Thanks!

EDIT: I solved it. I had to tick 'ksoap2.jar' under project>properties>java build path>Order and Export. It doesn't give the errors now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also encounter the similar problem with ksoap, I think you dont have ksoap dependence jar file added in your application, make sure it is 143kb in size and remove old one and add it again. Clean your project and run. This would remove your second error most probably. For first I think you are not passing correct parameters in
check it once

`requestObject.addProperty("UserIdentifier", "")`

Comment: Can you give a download link? I try a lot of them but none work.

Comment: Did you check the papameter name correctly coming from XML service..coz today only I had this problem and solved by cross checking the parameter names and the method i am accessing from services..

Comment: How to figure out what the data type of the parameters should be by looking at the wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

Change library for solving your problem.